# Should I store the values in dictionary or compute on-the-fly?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a problem where I have tuples called state and action and I want to compute its "binary features". The function to compute the features of state and action are described below. Mind you this is just a toy code.

I have about 700,000 combination of states and actions. I also need to have the features in numpy array/scipy sparse matrix.

Now, the problem is, I have to compute the features of states and actions million times. I have in mind 2 options.

One option is to compute beforehand using the function below all the 700,000 combinations and store it in a dictionary. The keys are (state, action) and the values are the binary features.

The other option is to call the function below every time I want to find the value of the binary feature of each state and action.

My objective is to get a good performance and also be memory efficient.

```
from numpy import array
from scipy import sparse

def compute_features(state, action):
    # state and action are 3-tuples of integers. 
    # e.g. (1, 2, 3)
    return array(state) - array(action)

def computer_binary_features(state, action, coord_size):
    # e.g. 
    # features = (1, 0, 2)
    # sizes = (2, 2, 3)
    # Meaning, the size of first coordinate is 2, second is 2 and third is 3.
    # It means the first coordinate can only take value integers 0 to 7.
    #
    # What this function does is turning (1, 0, 2) into binary features.
    # For the first coordinate, the value is 1 and the size is 2, so the binary
    # features of the first coordinate it (0, 1).
    # Second coordinate, the value is 0 and the size is 2. The binary features 
    # is (1, 0)
    # Third coordinate, the value is 2 and the size is 3. The binary features is
    # (0, 0, 1).
    # 
    # So the binary features of (1, 0, 2) is: (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    #
    # This function does not do concatenation but rather finding position of ones
    # in the binary features of size sum(sizes).
    # returns a coo sparse 0-1 valued 1 x n matrix.
    features = compute_features(state, action)
    coord_size = array(coord_size)
    col = []
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(features)):
        index = index + coord_size[i]
        col.append(index + features[i] - min_elem[i])
    row = [0] * len(col)
    data = [1] * len(col)
    mtx = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), (1, sum(coord_size)),
                            dtype=np.uint8)
    return mtx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is highly critical to return the results as fast as possible, than you should consider option one. However, you should keep in mind the memory and setup time overhead, which might be too expensive.

If performance is not an issue at all, you should prefer option two. This will make your code simpler and will not increase memory consumption and setup time unnecessarily.

If performance does play some role, but does not have to be AS GOOD AS POSSIBLE EVERY SINGLE TIME, I suggest to combine the two options. 
To enjoy both worlds, you can use [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Basically, it means you calculate results on demand, but just before returning them, you put them in a dictionary, as you suggested. The function will try to look for the result in the dictionary, and calculate the result only if necessary. 
[Here](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php) is a nice tutorial for implementing memoization in python.

Comment: Python 3.2+ has the [@functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator just for this purpose.

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to take a look at that.

Comment: I chose the first option and the performance is almost 400% faster.